# Javascript validation error in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation

I am getting a javascript validation error on my "Customer Search" page, when I click my "Search" button.

```
<asp:Button id="btnCustomerSearch" runat="server" onclientclick="return ValidateCustomer(1);" 
                                    Text="Continue" OnClick="btnCustomerSearch_Click" />
```

The error message is:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'ValidateCustomer' is undefined
```

however, in my ValidationFunctions.js, the ValidateCustomer function does exist.
How come the aspx cannot see that function (and how can I fix the issue) ?

**Update:**
The above issues are being caused as a result of the js file includes not being accurately referenced. However, I have an Alert messagebox in my code behind as indicated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906422/displaying-alert-boxes-in-asp-net-from-code-behind-does-not-always-work) and the alert message box don't appear as well. So this maybe a machine related issue.

How would I determine if the issue is machine related?

Comment: are you properly referencing your `ValidationFunctions.js` file?

Comment: Could you post that function here? Also, are you *sure* that this JS is linked at the page?

Comment: Are you sure you are referencing the script file correctly? Can you actually look at the source and navigate to it?

Comment: Can you also post the `ValidateCustomer` function?  And also where it's referenced in your ASPX file?

Comment: This is a master page application. So I can see the <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/ValidationFunctions.js"></script> on the .Master file

Comment: @DotNetRookie Is that path valid? Can you use another function from the same JS?

Comment: Can you please check in Firebug whether ValidationFunctions.js is downloaded to client? And any error raised in Console?

Comment: @AndreCalil yes, it is a valid path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is a master page application. So I can see the `<script
>   type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/ValidationFunctions.js"></script>`
>   on the .Master file

That might be a problem if the page you are on is in a subdirectory different from where the MasterPage is on.

One alternative I prefer is to add the external javascript files inside the ScriptManager if I am using one:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="SM1" runat="server">
  <Scripts>
    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/ValidationScript.js" />
  </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

This guarantees that the script reference is always resolved to the proper path because the ScriptManager is a service-side control and uses `ResolveClientUrl` to resolve the path `~/js/ValidationScript.js`.

If this is not an option or does not apply, I would reference the external JS files from the master page as so:

```
<head runat="server" id="page_header">
  <script type="text/javascript" src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/js/Validation.js")%>'  />
</head>
```

This guarantees that `js` directory is always resolved correctly regardless of where the page or the control is located.

Comment: wierd reaction.... when I include your script on the master page <script type="text/javascript" src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/js/Validation.js")%>'  />   the application's start page does not load at all.... just keeps attempting to load but the start page never appears. When I change it back to my original script <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/ValidationFunctions.js"></script> the start page loads fine

Comment: @DotNetRookie very strange. I just tested in my PC and definitely works fine. `<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js") %>' ></script>
</head>`. The script path resolves properly. Without `ResolveClientUrl` returns the incorrect path when the page is not in the same directory as the MasterPage.